# Slow XML shredding in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a stored procedure that takes a collection of "Survey" objects and shreds them into their appropriate tables.

The "Survey" object has two child objects, "Erosions" and "Spans".

Here is an example of the XML I might use:

```
<Surveys>
  <Survey>
    <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
    <CulvertID>5</CulvertID>
    <PRNo>587180</PRNo>
    <MP>5.243</MP>
    <RefMiles>1.500</RefMiles>
    <PtID>ABCGEFGH</PtID>
    <FWVersion>10</FWVersion>
    <SurveyDate>2012-08-27</SurveyDate>
    <FutureComments>7c36fe43-78cb-436e-81cf-f416aa63c8fc</FutureComments>
    <Erosions>
      <Erosion>
        <ID>160</ID>
        <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
        <Location>Test Erosion - 8/27/2012 - 1:19:04 PM</Location>
      </Erosion>
      <Erosion>
        <ID>161</ID>
        <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
        <Location>Test Erosion - 8/27/2012 - 1:19:04 PM</Location>
      </Erosion>
    </Erosions>
    <Spans>
      <Span>
        <ID>88</ID>
        <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
        <Material>Test Span - 8/27/2012 - 1:19:04 PM</Material>
      </Span>
      <Span>
        <ID>89</ID>
        <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
        <Material>Test Span - 8/27/2012 - 1:19:04 PM</Material>
      </Span>
    </Spans>
  </Survey>
</Surveys>
```

I've uploaded the stored procedure definition to the following location (too big to paste here).  [Download SQL](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2a9juOXyaH0RnowUlViVUdGOFk)

When I send in the XML sample provided above, the procedure takes about 10 seconds to complete, and that is with only a very small XML string.  It can take minutes to update/insert a record that includes values in any of the "VARBINARY(MAX)" columns.

I am truly an Xquery newbie... not sure what I've done wrong, but the performance is absolutely terrible.  Any suggestions?

***EDIT WITH SOLUTION:***

Following @wBob suggestions below, I have come up with [this SQL](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2a9juOXyaH0WTYwUHdRSnhoM1E) for my stored procedure.  I ended up redefining the PKs on my tables to be more "accurate".  Instead of a generated int ID, it's based on actual data fields.  This allowed me to use merge to insert child objects using a foreign key that was defined by actual data values, instead of a generated number that I would have to retrieve.

Comment: What SQL system are you using. Whatever do you mean by 'shred'?

Comment: @bmargulies MS SQL 2008.  By Shredding I mean to take the XML representation of an object and break it apart into the various tables used to define that object (including any child objects).

Comment: If performance is a concern and especially if you're dealing with large XML data you should use a streaming API like SAX rather than creating an object.   There is likely a tool for MS SQL that will do this mapping for you (I seem to recall there being some nice upload tools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a go at altering your (quite large) proc.  Please remember this is sample script to demonstrate a principle ( ie the MERGE with OUTPUT clause ), and it's up to you to finish and test it.  For example you'll need to test all columns are inserted / updated correctly, check your datatypes, and where I've removed the NULLIFs etc.  I would also add TRY/CATCH error and transaction handling.  Please note, I've also done the MERGE based on surveyId - not sure if that is correct?

If I were you, I'd spend some time getting familiar with [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) and the [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause before taking this on, but good luck and let us know how you get on.

I've also attached a [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6eGKNVGuBJddEpxbmRhTDBQZzQ) to my complete test rig.  This script is safe and completely rerunnable in your tempdb.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SaveSurvey]
    @XMLobject XML
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    CREATE TABLE #tmp_survey ( surveyId INT PRIMARY KEY, erosions XML, spans XML )

    BEGIN TRAN

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- MERGE dbo.CULV_StreamCrossingSurvey START
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.CULV_StreamCrossingSurvey ON

    ;MERGE dbo.CULV_StreamCrossingSurvey AS target
    USING
    (
    SELECT
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(SurveyID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS INT) AS SurveyID,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(CulvertID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS INT) AS CulvertID,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(County/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS County,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RoadName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS RoadName,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PRNo/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS INT) AS PRNo,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(MP/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,3)) AS MP,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RefMiles/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,3)) AS RefMiles,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PtID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)'), '') AS PtID,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(FWVersion/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS SMALLINT) AS FWVersion,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(Latitude/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS FLOAT) AS Latitude,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(Longitude/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS FLOAT) AS Longitude,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(Waterway/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS Waterway,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(SiteID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS SiteID,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(Observers/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS Observers,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(SurveyDate/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS DATE) AS SurveyDate,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(AdjacentLandowner/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS AdjacentLandowner,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(LocationComments/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS LocationComments,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(CrossingType/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS SMALLINT) AS CrossingType,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureShape/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS StructureShape,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(InletStructure/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS InletStructure,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(OutletStructure/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS OutletStructure,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(OutletType/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS OutletType,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(SubstrateInStructure/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS SubstrateInStructure,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(GeneralCondition/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS GeneralCondition,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PluggedPercent/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS SMALLINT) AS PluggedPercent,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PluggedLocation/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS PluggedLocation,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(CrushedPercent/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS SMALLINT) AS CrushedPercent,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(CrushedLocation/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS CrushedLocation,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsRustedThrough/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsRustedThrough,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureInterior/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS StructureInterior,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureWaterDepthInlet/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS StructureWaterDepthInlet,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureWaterDepthOutlet/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS StructureWaterDepthOutlet,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureEmbeddedDepthInlet/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS StructureEmbeddedDepthInlet,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureEmbeddedDepthOutlet/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS StructureEmbeddedDepthOutlet,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureWaterVelocityInlet/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS StructureWaterVelocityInlet,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureWaterVelocityOutlet/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS StructureWaterVelocityOutlet,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureWaterVelocityMeasured/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS StructureWaterVelocityMeasured,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StructureWaterVelocityMeasuredWith/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS StructureWaterVelocityMeasuredWith,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsPerched/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsPerched,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PerchHeight/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS PerchHeight,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(StreamFlow/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS StreamFlow,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsScourPoolPresent/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsScourPoolPresent,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ScourPoolLength/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS ScourPoolLength,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ScourPoolWidth/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS ScourPoolWidth,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ScourPoolDepth/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS ScourPoolDepth,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsUpstreamPondPresent/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsUpstreamPondPresent,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(UpstreamPondLength/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS UpstreamPondLength,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(UpstreamPondWidth/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS UpstreamPondWidth,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RiffleWaterDepth/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS RiffleWaterDepth,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RiffleBankfullWidth/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS RiffleBankfullWidth,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RiffleWettedWidth/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS RiffleWettedWidth,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RiffleWaterVelocity/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS RiffleWaterVelocity,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RiffleMeasuredWith/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS RiffleMeasuredWith,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RiffleSubstrate/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS RiffleSubstrate,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RoadSurface/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS RoadSurface,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RoadCondition/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS RoadCondition,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RoadWidth/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS RoadWidth,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(LocationOfLowPoint/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS LocationOfLowPoint,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(RunOffPath/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS RunOffPath,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(FillDepthUpStream/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS FillDepthUpStream,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(FillDepthDownStream/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS FillDepthDownStream,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(SlopeUpStream/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS SlopeUpStream,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(SlopeDownStream/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS SlopeDownStream,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ApproachLengthLeft/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS ApproachLengthLeft,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ApproachLengthRight/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(6,1)) AS ApproachLengthRight,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ApproachSlopeLeft/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS ApproachSlopeLeft,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ApproachSlopeRight/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS ApproachSlopeRight,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(VegetationDitchLeft/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS VegetationDitchLeft,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(VegetationDitchRight/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS VegetationDitchRight,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsErosionPresent/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsErosionPresent,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsErosionCorrectable/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsErosionCorrectable,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ErosionExtent/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS ErosionExtent,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(ErosionNotes/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS ErosionNotes,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsPrioritySite/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsPrioritySite,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PriorityReason/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS PriorityReason,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PriorityComments/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS PriorityComments,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(FutureVisit/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS FutureVisit,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(FutureComments/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS FutureComments,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(NonNativeInvasiveSpecies/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS NonNativeInvasiveSpecies,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(SpeciesObserved/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS SpeciesObserved,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsHeadChanged/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsHeadChanged,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(HeadChangeComments/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS HeadChangeComments,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsBackwatered/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsBackwatered,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(BackwaterComments/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS BackwaterComments,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsOvertopping/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsOvertopping,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(OvertoppingComments/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS OvertoppingComments,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(IsSubstrateEntireLength/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), '') AS BIT) AS IsSubstrateEntireLength,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(CalculatedPassability/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS CalculatedPassability,
        CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(DefinedPassability/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS DefinedPassability,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PassabilityComments/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS PassabilityComments,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoInlet/text())[1]', 'VARBINARY(MAX)'), '') AS PhotoInlet,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoInletFileName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS PhotoInletFileName,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoOutlet/text())[1]', 'VARBINARY(MAX)'), '') AS PhotoOutlet,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoOutletFileName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS PhotoOutletFileName,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoUpstream/text())[1]', 'VARBINARY(MAX)'), '') AS PhotoUpstream,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoUpstreamFileName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS PhotoUpstreamFileName,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoDownstream/text())[1]', 'VARBINARY(MAX)'), '') AS PhotoDownstream,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoDownstreamFileName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS PhotoDownstreamFileName,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoRoadApproachLeft/text())[1]', 'VARBINARY(MAX)'), '') AS PhotoRoadApproachLeft,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoRoadApproachLeftFileName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS PhotoRoadApproachLeftFileName,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoRoadApproachRight/text())[1]', 'VARBINARY(MAX)'), '') AS PhotoRoadApproachRight,
        NULLIF(X.survey.value('(PhotoRoadApproachRightFileName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS PhotoRoadApproachRightFileName,
        Erosions = (CASE WHEN CAST(X.survey.query('Erosions') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = '' THEN NULL
        ELSE X.survey.query('Erosions') END),
        Spans = (CASE WHEN CAST(X.survey.query('Spans') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = '' THEN NULL
        ELSE X.survey.query('Spans') END)
    FROM @XMLobject.nodes('Surveys/Survey') AS X(survey)
    ) AS source ON source.SurveyId = target.SurveyId

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
        THEN 
        INSERT ( surveyId, CulvertID, County, RoadName, PRNo, MP, RefMiles, PtID, FWVersion, Latitude, Longitude, Waterway, SiteID, Observers, SurveyDate, AdjacentLandowner, LocationComments, CrossingType, StructureShape, InletStructure, OutletStructure, OutletType, SubstrateInStructure, GeneralCondition, PluggedPercent, PluggedLocation, CrushedPercent, CrushedLocation, IsRustedThrough, StructureInterior, StructureWaterDepthInlet, StructureWaterDepthOutlet, StructureEmbeddedDepthInlet, StructureEmbeddedDepthOutlet, StructureWaterVelocityInlet, StructureWaterVelocityOutlet, StructureWaterVelocityMeasured, StructureWaterVelocityMeasuredWith, IsPerched, PerchHeight, StreamFlow, IsScourPoolPresent, ScourPoolLength, ScourPoolWidth, ScourPoolDepth, IsUpstreamPondPresent, UpstreamPondLength, UpstreamPondWidth, RiffleWaterDepth, RiffleBankfullWidth, RiffleWettedWidth, RiffleWaterVelocity, RiffleMeasuredWith, RiffleSubstrate, RoadSurface, RoadCondition, RoadWidth, LocationOfLowPoint, RunOffPath, FillDepthUpStream, FillDepthDownStream, SlopeUpStream, SlopeDownStream, ApproachLengthLeft, ApproachLengthRight, ApproachSlopeLeft, ApproachSlopeRight, VegetationDitchLeft, VegetationDitchRight, IsErosionPresent, IsErosionCorrectable, ErosionExtent, ErosionNotes, IsPrioritySite, PriorityReason, PriorityComments, FutureVisit, FutureComments, NonNativeInvasiveSpecies, SpeciesObserved, IsHeadChanged, HeadChangeComments, IsBackwatered, BackwaterComments, IsOvertopping, OvertoppingComments, IsSubstrateEntireLength, CalculatedPassability, DefinedPassability, PassabilityComments, PhotoInlet, PhotoInletFileName, PhotoOutlet, PhotoOutletFileName, PhotoUpstream, PhotoUpstreamFileName, PhotoDownstream, PhotoDownstreamFileName, PhotoRoadApproachLeft, PhotoRoadApproachLeftFileName, PhotoRoadApproachRight, PhotoRoadApproachRightFileName )
        VALUES ( surveyId, CulvertID, County, RoadName, PRNo, MP, RefMiles, PtID, FWVersion, Latitude, Longitude, Waterway, SiteID, Observers, SurveyDate, AdjacentLandowner, LocationComments, CrossingType, StructureShape, InletStructure, OutletStructure, OutletType, SubstrateInStructure, GeneralCondition, PluggedPercent, PluggedLocation, CrushedPercent, CrushedLocation, IsRustedThrough, StructureInterior, StructureWaterDepthInlet, StructureWaterDepthOutlet, StructureEmbeddedDepthInlet, StructureEmbeddedDepthOutlet, StructureWaterVelocityInlet, StructureWaterVelocityOutlet, StructureWaterVelocityMeasured, StructureWaterVelocityMeasuredWith, IsPerched, PerchHeight, StreamFlow, IsScourPoolPresent, ScourPoolLength, ScourPoolWidth, ScourPoolDepth, IsUpstreamPondPresent, UpstreamPondLength, UpstreamPondWidth, RiffleWaterDepth, RiffleBankfullWidth, RiffleWettedWidth, RiffleWaterVelocity, RiffleMeasuredWith, RiffleSubstrate, RoadSurface, RoadCondition, RoadWidth, LocationOfLowPoint, RunOffPath, FillDepthUpStream, FillDepthDownStream, SlopeUpStream, SlopeDownStream, ApproachLengthLeft, ApproachLengthRight, ApproachSlopeLeft, ApproachSlopeRight, VegetationDitchLeft, VegetationDitchRight, IsErosionPresent, IsErosionCorrectable, ErosionExtent, ErosionNotes, IsPrioritySite, PriorityReason, PriorityComments, FutureVisit, FutureComments, NonNativeInvasiveSpecies, SpeciesObserved, IsHeadChanged, HeadChangeComments, IsBackwatered, BackwaterComments, IsOvertopping, OvertoppingComments, IsSubstrateEntireLength, CalculatedPassability, DefinedPassability, PassabilityComments, PhotoInlet, PhotoInletFileName, PhotoOutlet, PhotoOutletFileName, PhotoUpstream, PhotoUpstreamFileName, PhotoDownstream, PhotoDownstreamFileName, PhotoRoadApproachLeft, PhotoRoadApproachLeftFileName, PhotoRoadApproachRight, PhotoRoadApproachRightFileName )

    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE
            SET target.CulvertID = source.CulvertID

    -- DELETE section
    --WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    --  THEN DELETE

    OUTPUT source.surveyId, source.Erosions, source.Spans INTO #tmp_survey
    --OUTPUT $action
    ;


-- MERGE dbo.CULV_StreamCrossingSurvey END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DELETEs START
-- Remove existing erosion and span records
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DELETE e
FROM dbo.CULV_StreamCrossingErosion e
    INNER JOIN #tmp_survey s ON e.SurveyID = s.surveyId

DELETE e
FROM dbo.Culvert_StreamCrossingSpan e
    INNER JOIN #tmp_survey s ON e.SurveyID = s.surveyId

-- DELETEs END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- MERGE dbo.CULV_StreamCrossingErosion START
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;MERGE dbo.CULV_StreamCrossingErosion AS target
USING
(
    SELECT
          t.surveyId
        , NULLIF(E.erosion.value('(Location/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS Location
        , E.erosion.value('(Length/text())[1]', 'NUMERIC(6,1)') AS Length
        , E.erosion.value('(Width/text())[1]', 'NUMERIC(6,1)') AS Width
        , E.erosion.value('(Depth/text())[1]', 'NUMERIC(6,1)') AS Depth
        , E.erosion.value('(IsReachingStream/text())[1]', 'BIT') AS IsReachingStream
        , NULLIF(E.erosion.value('(MaterialEroded/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS MaterialEroded
    FROM #tmp_survey t
        CROSS APPLY erosions.nodes('Erosions/Erosion') AS E(erosion)
) AS source ON source.SurveyId = target.SurveyId

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN 
    INSERT ( surveyId, Location, Length, Width, Depth, IsReachingStream, MaterialEroded )
    VALUES ( surveyId, Location, Length, Width, Depth, IsReachingStream, MaterialEroded )

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE
        SET 
        target.Location = source.Location,
        target.Length = source.Length,
        target.Width = source.Width,
        target.Depth = source.Depth,
        target.IsReachingStream = source.IsReachingStream,
        target.MaterialEroded = source.MaterialEroded
;

;MERGE dbo.Culvert_StreamCrossingSpan AS target
USING
(
    SELECT
        t.surveyId,
        S.span.value('(SpanNumber/text())[1]', 'SMALLINT') AS SpanNumber,
        S.span.value('(Length/text())[1]', 'NUMERIC(6,1)') AS Length,
        S.span.value('(Width/text())[1]', 'NUMERIC(6,1)') AS Width,
        S.span.value('(Height/text())[1]', 'NUMERIC(6,1)') AS Height,
        NULLIF( S.span.value('(Material/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '') AS Material
    FROM #tmp_survey t
        CROSS APPLY spans.nodes('Spans/Span') AS S(span)

) AS source ON source.SurveyId = target.SurveyId

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN 
    INSERT ( surveyID, SpanNumber, Length, Width, Height, Material )
    VALUES ( surveyID, SpanNumber, Length, Width, Height, Material )

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE
        SET 
        target.SpanNumber = source.SpanNumber,
        target.Length = source.Length,
        target.Width = source.Width,
        target.Height = source.Height,
        target.Material = source.Material
;

-- MERGE dbo.CULV_StreamCrossingErosion END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- !!TODO Add TRY/CATCH error and transaction handling

COMMIT

RETURN

END
GO
```

Comment: Wish I could give you extra credit for this answer!  Funny thing is, I had already gone down this road yesterday following your previous answer.  I must have been busy working on it the same time you were. I will post a copy of my SQL on my original question so you can see what I ended up doing.

Comment: Glad that's helped Amanda.  What kind of performance improvements are you seeing?

Comment: Well, when I send through a Survey object with 1 of the binary fields filled with a file about 1.5 mb in size, it used to take more than 5 minutes to execute.  Now it takes about 1.2 seconds.  When I send multiple files, it still takes less than 2 seconds.  So it's a very big improvement!  Thanks for all your help. =)

Answer (score 1):

there are a few changes I can recommend.  First of all, you don't need both .query and .value.  .query returns XML, so if you want XML then you use .query.  .value returns a scalar value, so that's the one you need to use here, eg

```
SELECT
    CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(SurveyID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS INT) AS SurveyID,
    CAST(NULLIF(X.survey.value('(CulvertID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'), '') AS INT) AS CulvertID,
```

Also, add the text() constructor and 1 ordinal (as above) which should be more efficient as per [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345118.aspx).

Secondly, I don't think you need the cursors.  .nodes returns a resultset so you can shred straight into a temp table, and then INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE into the main table.  If you are using SQL 2008 onwards, you can use MERGE, which does all operations in one.  You could even, if you're feeling brave, MERGE straight into the main tables from the .nodes resultset, if that makes sense?

If you don't get the required performance from these changes, you may consider using OPENXML, which can sometimes be faster for larger XML documents.  Be aware there is a well-known feature of OPENXML where it can automatically take up to 1/8 of your server's memory when called so you must always remember to call sp_xml_removedocument.

Have a go at making those changes and let us know how you get.

PS You are using the right terminology 'shred' and please ignore the note about SAX.  SQL Server has built into it very powerful and fast components for shredding XML.

Comment: I have removed the .query and replaced with only .value as you described in your post.  The performance has improved greatly!  Thank you!  I'd like to see if the performance can be increased further, so I am trying to find some examples showing the temp table and merge method you mentioned.  Since I have three tables, one parent table and two child tables, and the primary keys are generated in the table (not provided in the XML), I am uncertain how to proceed. I need to get the PK of the parent after insert to provide to the child. Does that make sense?